# How can we write a function `f` which returns an integer such that `f(x) == f(y)` if and only if `x` and `y` are the same?

Tags: python, python-3.x

## Requirements

Can we write a function `f` which:

- takes a single argument as input.
- returns an integer
- has the property that `f(x) == f(y)` if and only if `x` is exactly the same as `y` or `x` is a copy of `y`.

We say that "*`x` is exactly the same as `y` or `x` is a copy of `y`*" if at least one of the following conditions is met:

1. `id(x) == id(y)` returns `True`
2. `repr(x) == repr(y)` returns `True`
3. `x is y` returns `True`
4. `y is x` returns `True`
5. `x == copy.deepcopy(y)` returns `True`
6. `y == copy.deepcopy(x)` returns `True`

I realize that our function `f` will never be fool-proof, but please assume that nobody is going to define a new class with a really weird `__eq__` method.

Also assume that no adversary is going to define a new class with a truly bizarre `__copy__` method or some sort of pathological `__deepcopy__()`.

## One Attempt at Defining `f`

My feeble attempt at defining a function `f` is shown below:

```python
pi = lambda k_1, k_2: (1/2)*(k_1 + k_2)(k_1 + k_2 + 1)+k_2

def f(x:object) -> int:
    """
        Based on something called "Cantor's pairing function"
        from the field of mathematics. 
    """   
    k_1 = hash(x)
    k_2 = hash(type(x))
    if k_1 < 0 or k_2 < 0:
        raise NotImplementedError()
    return pi(k_1, k_2)
```

## Flaws in my solution

There are some issues:

- I worry that two different objects will have the same hash value. For example, maybe `hash([1, 2]) == hash([2, 3])`. The two lists `[1, 2]` and `[2, 3]` are different, but might have different hash values. Feel free to correct me if I am wrong.
- my solution only works when `hash()`returns a non-negative integer.

## `id(x) == id(y)` versus `x == y`

`x == y` is implemented as `x.__eq__(y)`

Note that the `id` of an object is generally not the same as the `id` of a ***copy*** of that object. Usually, an object and a copy of the object usually reside at different memory addresses.

The following code demonstrates the difference between `__eq__()` and `id()`:

```py
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [1, 2, 3]
print("id(x)".ljust(15), id(x))
print("id(y)".ljust(15), id(y))
print("x is x".ljust(15), x is x)
print("x is y".ljust(15), x is y)
print("x == x".ljust(15), x == x)
print("x == y".ljust(15), x == y)
```

We have:

```
id(x)           2531180442688
id(y)           2531180443264
x is x          True
x is y          False
x == x          True
x == y          True
```

## Worry a little bit, but not too much about custom-made `__repr__` or `__eq__`

I realize that our function `f` will never be fool-proof, but please assume that nobody is going to define a new class with a really weird `__eq__`, `__hash__` method, or `__eq__` method.

For example, someone could (in theory) define the following:

```py
import random

class NoNoNo:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.myVal = random.randint(1, 9)
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False
    def __repr__(self):
        return "$"
```

Objects instantiated from the `NoNoNo` class are *never* equal to each-other.

```py
import copy
x = NoNoNo()
y = copy.deepcopy(x)
print("x == y?", "Yes" if x == y else "No") # prints "x == y? No"
```

Also, `repr(x)` is always the same as `repr(y)`

```py
import copy
x = NoNoNo()
y = NoNoNo() # `y` IS VERY DIFFERENT FROM `x`
print("repr(x) == repr(y)?", "Yes" if repr(x) == repr(y) else "No") # prints "repr(x) == repr(y)? Yes"
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this if it has to work for arbitrary types with arbitrary levels of nesting.

Comment: **Usually, an object and a copy of the object usually reside at different memory addresses.** Not just usually, *always*. Otherwise it would be the same object, not a copy.

Comment: Note that you cannot hash a list, so the examples with the `hash([1,2])` don't work

Comment: Regarding your requirements, if I'm not mistaken, there is a strong correlation between them- ([1] = [3] = [4]) -> ([5]=[6]) and  ([1] = [3] = [4]) -> [2]. Also, probably in most cases ([5] = [6]) -> [2]. So basically, it seems to me that [2] is the only condition we want to look at, since it's the weekest. Makes sense?

Comment: Condition 4 is redundant. If `x is y` is true then by definition `y is x` is also true.

Comment: @Barmar wouldn't that also be redundant with 1. `id(x) == id(y)`?

Comment: @Guy I understand you. When you write something like [1] -> [3] you mean that condition #1 implies condition #3. That is, if **[`id(x) == id(y)` returns `True`]** then it follows that **[`x is y` returns `True`]**

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes. 1, 3, and 4 are all basically saying the same thing.

Comment: @Guy `is` is often used as a shortcut when you don't know if `==` is going to take a long time.  The only case I know where that fails is with `float('nan')`.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes, when writing [i] = [j] i meant that requirement i is exactly the same as requirement j, and when I wrote [i] -> [j] I meant that requirement [j] derives from requirement [i], and that means that requirement j is "easier to satify"

Comment: @Guy I'm just saying there's justification for using e.g. condition 3 even if it's not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, it means that the weakest condition is condition [2], and that's the condition we want to aim for when implementing the function. (I hope the condition wasn't added by mistake).

Does the following function make sense?

```
def f(x):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x *256 + y, repr(x).encode('latin1'))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for types with repr `"\0"`, `"\0\0"`, etc. They all clash.

Comment: Can you give me an example of two values which clash? Running on  `"\0"`, `"\0\0"` gives different results

Comment: No, a type with its *repr* being `"\0"`, not the string `"\0"` itself (which would have repr `'"\0"'`).

Comment: In the request it was stated not to worry to much about such cases. Anyway, handling such cases means removing requirement [2] as an option, right? Because it basically means we can't "trust" the repr as a good identifier.

Comment: No, see my answer, you can deal with zero-extended strings by encoding the length.

Answer (score 0):

I will limit myself to the case `repr(x) == repr(y)`. This covers all except the deepcopy bases, assuming `repr` is deterministic. Then it essentially comes down to compressing a string down to a single integer in a unique fashion. This (well, it's inverse) is known as a [universal code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_code_(data_compression)).

A way to do that is to take the string and convert it to bytes. Take note of the length `l` of the string. Check how many bits it takes to represent `l`. Then, output that many `1` bits followed by a `0`. Then `l` itself encoded in binary, and finally the bytes in, say, little-endian encoding.

```py
def encode(s):
    bytes = s.encode("utf-8")
    l = len(s)
    b = l.bit_length()
    ones = (1 << b) - 1
    lshift = l << (b + 1)
    bytesshift = (int.from_bytes(bytes, "little") << (2*b + 1))
    return ones | lshift | bytesshift

def decode(n):
    b = 0
    while n % 2:
        b += 1
        n >>= 1
    n >>= 1

    l = n & ((1 << b) - 1)
    n >>= b
    return n.to_bytes(l, "little").decode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is feasible to implement. With arbitrary types any sort of paring function will lead to massive ints to represent everything except the most simple structures.

Ideally you would have to pair the data type and the data together to get a unique integer. The data will need to be converted into an integer unique to the set of all possible data inputs, which in practice would become very large very fast. Paired with the data types integer representation you will end up with a huge number the majority of the time.

If you want to handle negative hash values you could have a look at using a [Signed Cantor Pairing Function.](https://www.vertexfragment.com/ramblings/cantor-szudzik-pairing-functions/#:%7E:text=A%20pairing%20function%20is%20a,to%20a%20single%2C%20unique%20value.&text=This%20is%20useful%20in%20a,from%20a%20pair%20of%20values.) You would still have hash collisions however.

The best way I can see if simply concatenating the hash of the data structure with the data itself but then you may as well just keep the objects as they are. This could also lead to hash collisions between data types but unless you use tonnes of types it's unlikely. You could also use a perfect hash but you would have to define the set of allowed datatypes beforehand.